# Using fopen() to write file into subdirectory

Tags: php, directory, fopen

I already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837337/trying-to-write-a-file-to-a-different-directory-using-fopen) StackOverflow question and it didn't help (similarly titled).

I'm passing an image in from my Android application.  If I type

```
$file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');
```

It works correctly and the image uploads; however, I want to allow for multiple uploads from android phones, so I want to randomize the name of the .jpg file so that I can save each new upload as a different name.  I was trying this below:

```
$destination =  time() + rand(1, 1000) . ".jpg";
$url_destination = "/project_images/" . $destination;

$file = fopen($url_destination, 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
```

It doesn't write the file to the server, however.  I tried different variations of the URL there - with 'project_images/', '/project_images/', even trying the full URL (which the aforementioned StackOverflow post corrected me on), and I still can't get it to write.

The permissions of the project_images folder are set to allow files to be written to it.  Any ideas?

Comment: `fopen` cannot write to a URL, so `$url_destination` is definitely starting on the wrong foot. The path must be a local filesystem path.

Comment: try to change permissions to 777 for /project_images directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to write a file to a different directory using fopen()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837337/trying-to-write-a-file-to-a-different-directory-using-fopen)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario The OP already stated in his question that that question doesn't fix his problem.

Comment: @JaredMcAteer - The OP admitted later that "he didn't upload properly".

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario my bad I see that now... review panel doesn't give the answers as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is `"/project_images"` which is a wrong absolute path.

For it to work change it to `"project_images/"` or `dirname(__FILE__).'/project_images/'`.

Comment: I thought I had tried that one already (see my post where I actually included that!), but I guess it didn't upload properly.  This solved it.

Comment: Great :) .. usually using dirname(__FILE__) is the best solution in these cases

Comment: Another improvement of your code .. try to stick to ' instead of " if you don't use code like this : $str = "content of test is $test";

Answer (score 1):

For those who use XAMPP on Windows: use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead `/`

```
dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'project_images'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
```